# Convert 3 Matrices to 1 plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, graph

I'm trying to combine 3 matrices to one plot.

I'm trying to simulate a mark-recapture scenario. However, instead of having 1 population, there are 3 (which are contained in each of their matrices).

Because I want to sample from each population once, the x-axis will range from 0-300. However, 1-100 on the x-axis will correspond to the samples collected from population:

[image]

101-200 from population 2

[image]

201-300 from population 3. The only deviation from the picture is that I'd like a continuous line, from 0-300.

I have the code to create these matrices and made each matrix the same size, but I don't know how to 1) convert and plot them using ggplot2 2) put all three on one graph

```
## Population size
N <- 400
N 

## Vector labeling each item in the population
pop <- c(1:N)
pop

## Lower and upper bounds of sample size
lower.bound <- round(x = .05 * N, digits = 0)
lower.bound ## Smallest possible sample size

upper.bound <- round(x = .15 * N, digits = 0)
upper.bound ## Largest possible sample size

## Length of sample size interval
length.ss.interval <- length(c(lower.bound:upper.bound))
length.ss.interval ## total possible sample sizes, ranging form lower.bound to upper.bound

## Determine a sample size randomly (not a global variable...simply for test purposes)
## Between lower and upper bounds set previously
## Give equal weight to each possible sample size in this interval
sample(x = c(lower.bound:upper.bound), 
       size = 1, 
       prob = c(rep(1/length.ss.interval, length.ss.interval)))

## Specify number of samples to take
n.samples <- 100

## Initiate empty matrix
## 1st column is population (item 1 thorugh item 400)
## 2nd through nth column are all rounds of sampling
dat <- matrix(data = NA, 
              nrow = length(pop), 
              ncol = n.samples + 1)

dat[,1] <- pop


## Take samples of random sizes
## Record results in columns 2 through n
## 1 = sampled (marked)
## 0 = not sampled (not marked)
for(i in 2:ncol(dat)) {
  a.sample <- sample(x = pop, 
                     size = sample(x = c(lower.bound:upper.bound), 
                                   size = 1, 
                                   prob = c(rep(1/length.ss.interval, length.ss.interval))), 
                     replace = FALSE)
  dat[,i] <- dat[,1] %in% a.sample
}

## How large was each sample size?
apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)
## 1st element is irrelevant
## 2nd element through nth element: sample size for each of the 100 samples


schnabel.comp <- data.frame(sample = 1:n.samples, 
                            n.sampled = apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)[2:length(apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum))] 
)

## First column: which sample, 1-100
## Second column: number selected in that sample


## How many items were previously sampled?
## For 1st sample, it's 0
## For 2nd sample, code is different than for remaning samples

n.prev.sampled <- c(0, rep(NA, n.samples-1))
n.prev.sampled

n.prev.sampled[2] <- sum(ifelse(test = dat[,3] == 1 & dat[,2] == 1, 
                                yes = 1, 
                                no = 0))

n.prev.sampled

for(i in 4:ncol(dat)) {
  n.prev.sampled[i-1] <- sum(ifelse(test = dat[,i] == 1 & rowSums(dat[,2:(i-1)]) > 0, 
                                    yes = 1, 
                                    no = 0))
}

schnabel.comp$n.prev.sampled <- n.prev.sampled

## n.newly.sampled: in each sample, how many items were newly sampled?
## i.e., never seen before?
schnabel.comp$n.newly.sampled <- with(schnabel.comp, 
                                      n.sampled - n.prev.sampled)

## cum.sampled: how many total items have you seen?
schnabel.comp$cum.sampled <- c(0, cumsum(schnabel.comp$n.newly.sampled)[2:n.samples-1])

## numerator of schnabel formula
schnabel.comp$numerator <- with(schnabel.comp, 
                                n.sampled * cum.sampled) 

## denominator of schnable formula is n.prev.sampled

## pop.estimate -- after each sample (starting with 2nd -- need at least two samples)
schnabel.comp$pop.estimate <- NA

for(i in 1:length(schnabel.comp$pop.estimate)) {
  schnabel.comp$pop.estimate[i] <- sum(schnabel.comp$numerator[1:i]) / sum(schnabel.comp$n.prev.sampled[1:i])
}


## Plot population estimate after each sample
if (!require("ggplot2")) {install.packages("ggplot2"); require("ggplot2")}
if (!require("scales")) {install.packages("scales"); require("scales")}


small.sample.dat <- schnabel.comp

small.sample <- ggplot(data = small.sample.dat, 
                       mapping = aes(x = sample, y = pop.estimate)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = N, col = "red", lwd = 1) +   
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0:100), ylim = c(300:500)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(11)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(11)) + 
  labs(x = "\nSample", y = "Population estimate\n", 
       title = "Sample sizes are between 5% and 15%\nof the population") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

small.sample
```

Comment: Could you draw a diagram of how you want your graphic to look? Its not clear how your matrices relate to ggplot aesthetics and geoms...

Comment: Sorry about that! Added an image of the plots I've created, I'm just now having trouble combining them

Comment: I don't want to overlay them -- I'd like to combine into a continuous dotplot of estimates

Comment: Those dotplots in your question are a plot of (x,y) as lines. Where's your y values in your example? All I can see are big matrices.

Comment: I've added the original code I used (to produce one graph for one population) I was providing the matrices version because it was similar. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is...

Given three data frames like this:

```
> d1
  x           y
1 1 0.899683096
2 2 0.604513234
3 3 0.005824789
4 4 0.442692758
5 5 0.103125175
> d2
  x          y
1 1 0.35260029
2 2 0.06248654
3 3 0.79272047
> d3
  x         y
1 1 0.4791399
2 2 0.2583674
3 3 0.1283629
4 4 0.7133847
```

Construct `d`:

```
> d = rbind(d1,d2,d3)
> d$x = 1:nrow(d)
> d
    x           y
1   1 0.899683096
2   2 0.604513234
3   3 0.005824789
4   4 0.442692758
5   5 0.103125175
6   6 0.352600287
7   7 0.062486543
8   8 0.792720473
9   9 0.479139947
10 10 0.258367356
11 11 0.128362933
12 12 0.713384651
```

And then plot x against y as normal.